# Looking to build a WPF XBap with full trust, can a purchased certificate get past some of the security issues?

Tags: wpf, serial-port, xbap, certificate

We are developing an application that needs to talk to some hardware (serial port) on the machine, and most of what we do is WPF and .net, so an xbap seems logical.

My concern is with the certifcates.  I have seen a bunch of people showing how to create and self sign applications, but then the user is required to install that to their machine manual to trust the root.  I am curious if we purchase an cert from say Verisign if that requirement will then go away?

I have no problem if there is a prompt requesting full trust, but I do not want my remote users dealing with installing certificates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you purchase a code signing certificate from a trusted authority then the users will not need to do anything with certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If your certificate comes from a trusted authority, the users won't generally need to worry about it (where it becomes an issue is if you let your certificate lapse). If you're a member of Code Project, you can get a "cheap" certificate from one of their partners. More information [here](http://www.codeproject.com/services/certificates/index.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution here =D 
[XBAP full trust deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100947/xbap-full-trust-deployment)
create your own certificate and deploy full trust. 0 cost. if you're looking something like secure layer cert, you may head on http://www.comodo.com/business-security/digital-certificates/ssl-certificates.php?entryURL= for free SSL