# XBAP full trust deployment

Tags: deployment, certificate, xbap, full-trust

I did the following steps to deploy my wpf application that need full trust permission:

1-Creating a certificate using makecert.exe

2-Creating signed application and deployment manifests.

3-Building a website in IIS to host files (include MyApplication.exe.manifest and MyAppicatio.xbap)

4-Adding certificate - used to sign manifests - to IE certificate store (Trustes Root Certification Authorities and Trusted Publishers) , IE Menu bar->Tools Internet Options->Content->Certificates

But when i try to browse Xbap file in IE6 it throws Not granted exception for dowloading MyApplication.exe.manifest file.

When i grant access using caspol.exe tool to my deployment url , it works well.

But how can i make certifcate approach works correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem , my created certificate was out of date (expired).

Comment: you can accept your answer to remove the question from the "Unanswered" list

Comment: Is there way to avoid Trust related pop up even when certificates are expired and Web HMI is being opened on separate Machine on same domain then Server or separate domain than Server?