# Deploy a full trust wpf browser application (XBAP)

Tags: .net, certificate, xbap, trust

I am building a XBAP application which required to run in a full trust environment. Thus, when using it on browser, the end-user have to install my .pfx file (to certificate my application) or receives the famous "Trust not granted" error. That make a inconvenience.

So, I want that everytime the end-user access my xbap application, it would asks the user to install the .pfx file and then auto-install the .pfx file.

How can I do that? (using VS2008, .net 3.5)

Answer (score 1):

The following link provides details on how you could code up a simple executable to install your certificate on the client's machine. You could then link to this executable from your web page. The client could then simply run this executable to install your certificate.

[Automate Certificate Install for XBAP Applications](http://www.managescope.com/2009/03/automate-certificate-install-for-xbap-applications/)

I'm thinking you could be even trickier and code up an active-x control that did something similar. This way the active-x control would automatically prompt the client to install the first time they visit your website.

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself as a trusted publisher, which means user needs install the certificate into "trusted publisher". check out more details at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01daf08f.aspx

Comment: Here is a related discussion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a8bfe373-291b-41b8-b2b2-4db92cbe54f0

Comment: I mean that the XBAP prompt a dialog (for example) to install the certificate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

there is a solution here =D 
[XBAP full trust deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100947/xbap-full-trust-deployment)
create your own certificate and deploy full trust.afterward, user install automatically for my case =D also can prompt to install or notify user click the button beside the address bar ^^

extra information, you may notice whether do your host support full trust =D